# Large project files in Heroku on Django

Tags: django, heroku

I have some large files that I need to store in my project. Their sum total size is 157 MB. When my application starts, I have an `AppConfig` which runs. It reads the files into memory and they stay there for the lifetime of the application. By the way, these files aren't static/media assets like images; they're numpy arrays for some server-side logic.

So I want a solution which accomplishes the following:

1. Keeps my files out of source control / the Heroku slug
2. Does not require me to read from some cloud service S3/Google frequently
3. Has my files readily available during the stage where `AppConfig`s are initialized.

Here is one solution that I thought of: Store the files in S3/Google, and download them from the server when `AppConfig` is initialized. The downside of this is that it would make restarting my server really slow because downloading 157 MB is pretty time-consuming, and it might cost a bit too.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have hard time finding ideal solution for heroku (without paying to someone)

These are some of thoughts:

- Keep datasets in database ( rows are not free on Heroku )
- Keep datasets in memcached/redis ( these instances are pretty expensive on heroku )

  OR
- Host your site on cheap VPS :)

Comment: I think you're right. Time to rent a good VPS because Heroku is way too limited for my use case.